# PluginNotFoundException: The "MenuSettings" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8

I'm getting the following error when saving nodes on a site that I just moved from one server to another:

```
Got error 'PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Component\\Plugin\\Exception\\PluginNotFoundException: "The "MenuSettings" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\\Core\\Validation\\ConstraintManager are: Callback, Blank, NotBlank, Email, CommentName, DateTimeFormat, FileUriUnique, FileValidation, jsonapi_extras__duplicate_field, LinkAccess, LinkExternalProtocols, LinkNotExistingInternal, LinkType, PathAlias, TaxonomyHierarchy, ProtectedUserField, UserMailRequired, UserMailUnique, UserName, UserNameUnique, MenuTreeHierarchy, Bundle, EntityChanged, EntityHasField, EntityType, EntityUntranslatableFields, ReferenceAccess, ValidReference, UniquePathAlias, ValidPath, AllowedValues, ComplexData, Null, Count, Length, NotNull, PrimitiveType, Range, Regex, UniqueField, Uuid" at /data/sites/web/whatevs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 53\n'
```

I haven't had this problem on the old server. I cleared the cache on the new server, and specifically the `cache_discovery` table. The problem disappears if I comment out the following line in `/core/modules/menu_ui/menu_ui.module` :

```
if (isset($entity_types['node'])) {
  $entity_types['node']->addConstraint('MenuSettings', []); // comment out this line
}
```

But I'm not too happy patching core just to get something working that ought to work and has worked. Does anyone understand where this comes from?

This is a Drupal 8 site where I imported an old Drupal 7 site's content; I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: take a look at this comment https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews/issues/3016609#comment-13444724 update your php to 7.3.0 or higher on your new server !

Comment: I just tried changing to PHP 7.3, and it sadly made no difference. I was running 7.2, which is not horribly outdated anyway.

Comment: `I was running 7.2, which is not horribly outdated anyway.` - well, Drupal 9 requires 7.3 (I know you are on 8, just saying). Anyway, this sounds like a cache problem, did you try clearing all caches and not just cache_discovery?

Comment: Yep. Cleared all caches first, and then made sure the cache_discovery was cleared.

Comment: Check that you have this file `/core/modules/menu_ui/src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/MenuSettingsConstraint.php`

Comment: @NoSssweat: I don't! 

My word, something must have gone very wrong transferring the files for this site. Makes me wonder what else I'm missing if there are files just blatantly missing. Time to re-copy core.